# Where can I find the generated .razor.g.cs files for Blazor components(.razor files)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, razor-components

Before .net 6, we can find the generated files at obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages.
But seems it's not the case in .net 6, and there is no information on this topic on the internet. Can you please tell me where can I find those generated .cs files for all the Blazor components?

Thank you.

Comment: .NET 6 uses source generators and doesn't save the generated files to disk. The files are generated during compilation,. As the duplicate shows you can use a flag to tell it to store the files and specify the desired path. You can find the Razor SDK flags and their defaults at [ASP.NET Core Razor SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-6.0)